# render monospace text correctly in Gmail Android app

Tags: android, gmail, html-email, text-rendering, monospace

I'm trying to display the following graph correctly in the Gmail app on Android (Version 10). Right now I have the following, which renders correctly in the browser and on most clients, but alas not in the app.

HTML

```
<pre>
     <code>
         14.00 ┤             ╭─╮              |
         13.60 ┤            ╭╯ ╰╮             |
         13.20 ┤           ╭╯   ╰╮         ╭─ |
         12.80 ┤           │     │        ╭╯  |
         12.40 ┤          ╭╯     ╰╮      ╭╯   |
         12.00 ┤        ╭─╯       ╰─╮    │    |
         11.60 ┤       ╭╯           ╰╮  ╭╯    |
         11.20 ┤     ╭─╯             ╰──╯     |
         10.80 ┤    ╭╯                        |
         10.40 ┤   ╭╯                         |
         10.00 ┼───╯                          |
     </code>
</pre>
```

CSS

```
code {
    font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, Roboto Mono, monospace, monospace
}
```

EDIT: I have just noticed that the graph in this question doesn't render correctly in the browser either. So the question rather becomes how to trigger monospace rendering on Android in general.

Comment: First, do make sure your fonts that have a space in them are wrapped in quotes, e.g. Monaco, 'Lucida Console', 'Liberation Mono'

Comment: In addition, it looks as though the only monospaced options you have for android are 'Droid Sans Mono' and 'Droid Serif Mono', so maybe add them to your font stack

Comment: Also try the CSS inline for both `pre` and `code`, it might fix a few things.